# How to handle action in Reducer?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

How do I target which element/object in array in a reducer I have to pass the action to? I am trying to figure out what action I take on the reducer. Or how do I change affect the `number` value in the object. So I am rendering the array in a View with TouchableOpacity which onPress Im calling the action dispatch as following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class NewData extends Component {
    render(){
    const renData = this.props.newData.map((data, idx) => {
        return (
            <View key={idx}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => this.props.incNum(data.id)}
                //not sure how to toggel dispatch call above, for onPress
              >
              <Text style={styles.welcome}>{data.id} - {data.name} - {data.number}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View> 
        )
    });

        return(
            <View>
          {renData}
      </View>   
        );
    }
}


function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
    newData: state.newData
  };
};


//I think I need to create a toggle here:
//Something like: this.props.newData.id ? incNum : decNum


function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return {
    incNum: (id) => {
      dispatch({
        type: "INC_NUM",
        payload: id
      })
    },
     decNum: (id) => {
      dispatch({
        type: "DEC_NUM",
        payload: id
      })
    }
  };
};  

export default connect( mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )( NewData )
```

My Reducer:

```
const initialState = [
      {
        id: '01',
        name: 'Name One',
        number: 11
      },
      {
        id: '02',
        name: 'Name Two',
        number: 22
      },
      {
        id: '03',
        name: 'Name Three',
        number: 33
      }

    ]

export default function newData (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INC_NUM":
      return {
        ...state,
        number: this.state.number ++ // <== need help here.
      }
    case "DEC_NUM":
      return {
        ...state,
        number: this.state.number --
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

I think `<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.incNum(data.id)}` will bind the `id` to be changed. And passing the `payload: id` will pass the id to the reducer. But how do I update the value in the reducer? I can do without the toggle for now. I want to learn about passing the value and updating accordingly in the reduder.

Thank you.

---

**EDIT1 :**

So my reducer now is:

```
const initialState = {
  1: {
     id: '01',
     name: 'Name One',
     number: 11
    },
  2: {
     id: '02',
     name: 'Name Two',
     number: 22
    }
}


export default function newData (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INC_NUM":
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload]: {
          ...state[action.payload], 
          number: state[action.payload].number++  <== Line 58 in ERROR screenshot
        }
    case "DEC_NUM":
        return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload]: {
          ...state[action.payload], 
          number: state[action.payload].number--
        }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

And the way I'm rendering it is:

```
class NewData extends Component {
  render(){

    const renData = Object.keys(this.props.newData).map((key, idx) => {
      let data = this.props.newData[key]
        return (
        <View key={idx}>
          <TouchableOpacity

            onPress={() => this.props.updateNum(data.id)}
          >
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>{data.id} - {data.name} - {data.number}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View> 
       )
    });

    return(
        <View>
            {renData}
        </View>   
    )
  }
}


function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return {
    updateNum: (id) => {
      INC_NUM({
        type: "INC_NUM",
        payload: id
      })
    }
  };
};
```

Everything in the reducer is appearing as expected. But when I click and the action is called, I get an error:

[image]

Comment: You need to do some filtering in your reducer. Your current reducer is attempting to update state.number, which doesn't exist.

Also your initialState should be an object not an array. I usually map my state by id like this:

{
    1: {id: 1, name: 'number one'...},
    2: {id:2,... },
....
}

Comment: Thank you. Could you please point me to something that I can read/refer to please. I'm new to React and Redux and trying to learn.

Comment: Also, you should be filtering your state object using your action.payload. This is where your 'id' is coming in. Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: I had to learn both about a year ago. I'd highly recomend working through React then Redux seperatly in a few tutorials before trying to combine learning both. http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html is a great start for redux. Feel free to PM me with any questions.  Another resource: https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux

Comment: Thanks .. I went through both mentioned tutorials several times since the past 2 months. My question, I guess, is more of JS related and I'm not able to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your reducer seems to be lot more complex that it needs to be, below is the simpler approach, hope this helps.

```
const initialState = {
  1: {
     id: '01',
     name: 'Name One',
     number: 11
    },
  2: {
     id: '02',
     name: 'Name Two',
     number: 22
    }
}


    export default function newData (state = initialState, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case "INC_NUM":
             const newState = {...state};
             newState[action.payload].nubmer++;
             return newState;

        case "DEC_NUM":
            const newState = {...state};
            newState[action.payload].nubmer--;
            return newState;

        default:
          return state
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried your code. There is no error. But I don't see any change in the `{data.number}`. It stays the same. Isn't that supposed to change?

Comment: Sorry. I changed the `id` in my reducer to the same as it was pointing to. Like for 1, I changed `id:01` to `id:1` and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appears to be in your reducer and the structure of your state.. you're not using the ID to identify which keyval pair to update.

First I'd modify your initialState to be an object and use the id as your keys:

```
const initialState = {
  1: {name: 'Name One', number: 11},
  2: {name: 'Name Two', number: 22},
  3: {name: 'Name Three', number: 33}
}
```

Then in your reducer:

```
case "INC_NUM":
  return {
    ...state,
    [action.id]: {
      ...state[action.id], 
      number: state[action.id].number++
    }
  }
```

I know the syntax is convoluted, but the spread operator is nice shorthand for what otherwise would be even harder to read.

Comment: Tried this and rendered the object correctly. Now I'm getting an error when I click on an item and call the `action`. Edited my question `EDIT1`. What am I missing/doing wrong? Also, am I rendering `renData` correctly?

Comment: Hi. How will I append more data to this state? I'm calling an API to add more data to the state but don;t know how to do it with an object. With an array it's easy (`...state, ...data`) please tell me how can I do the same with `Objects`.

Comment: In the above example, just replace `state[action.id].number++` with some new data (such as action.newpayload) and you'll append that data. Technically you are appending number++ in the example here.